# Pyramid app running on localhost not opening SQLAlchemy created JSON

Tags: javascript, python, json, d3.js, sqlalchemy

Through a Pyramid app using SQLAlchemy I created a JSON using 'df._tojson()'.
I am trying to import it using d3.json but have some difficulties making this connection. It is not working and my console states 'TypeError: typeData.forEach is not a function'. The console also correctly shows the data within 'data.json'

This particular JSON that SQLAlchemy produces is using the correct format. It even works when I use the url to 'data.json'. When I copy-paste the output data of the 'data.json' and store it as a static, the d3 script works completely fine.

Anyone an idea why .forEach works with a static JSON and not a SQLAlchemy produced JSON?

```
@view_config(route_name='data',
             renderer='json')

    def data(self):
        request = self.request
        session = request.session

        query = self.request.session.query(State)
        df = pd.read_sql(query.statement, query.session.bind)

        return df.to_json(orient='records')
```

---

```
d3.json("../data.json", function(error, typeData) {

   console.log(typeData);

   typeData.forEach(function(d) {
      d.type = d.type.match(/\d+/)
   });
```

---

```
'TypeError: typeData.forEach is not a function'
```

Comment: Most likely your server is returning the wrong Content-Type (should be `application/json` but probably defaulted to `text/plain`), but you'll have to post your server code to be sure.

Comment: @univerio, it looks like you are right, it is text/html as an output. I added my server view script as well. How can I do it correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@univerio, it looks like you are right, it is text/html as an output.

My view script is as follows:
How can I do it correctly?

```
@view_config(route_name='data',
             renderer='json')

    def data(self):
        request = self.request
        session = request.session

        query = self.request.session.query(State)
        df = pd.read_sql(query.statement, query.session.bind)

        return df.to_json(orient='records')
```